# Why the variable shows space?

Tags: batch-file

[image: space]

```
@echo on &setlocal
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    If "%computername%" == "DTCVDI-V33-0951" (
      SET NS=\\xx
       SET OPSDIR=!NS!\ProAdmin
       SET COGDIR=!NS!\CREM  
     )
    set "list=%COGDIR%\Config\Copy_Daily_EMTS_Reporting.txt"
    echo %list%
    pause
```

Here the list shows `\\xx\CREM  \Config\Copy_Daily_EMTS_Reporting.txt`.

Why this space shows and how to remove this?

Answer (score 2):

because you told it to do so. Your line

```
SET COGDIR=!NS!\CREM
```

has two spaces at the end, which are also assigned to the variable.

A better syntax is:

```
  SET "COGDIR=!NS!\CREM"
```

The quotes prevent unintended spaces.

Comment: Thank you so much.